# Pass reference id from url bar to other internal pages

Tags: forms, url, reference, field

I am compiling a lead generation landing page and, in the form I have inserted a hidden field which collect whatever is written in the url bar after 
"?rel=". 
This is done in order to track where the leads come from (Facebook ads, direct linking etc).

To be more clear if this is the url: www.mywebsite.com/form.html?rel=fbads

the hidden field will be fill with "fbads" and this is working.

In the landing page I have a link to another page with more details and in this webpage I have the same form.

My idea is to run campaings on the first page with the rel link, but then if the user clicks on the link and go to the detailed page (and then compile the form from there), I am losing the rel field.

How can I pass the rel field to the url of the second page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may refer the this stackoverflow [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354597/how-to-determine-where-a-user-came-from-to-my-site). Once the HTTP GET request comes, traverse in HTTP headers in your controller and look for Referer field but it is not always set and the client can change the header value. May be using google analytics is the better option.

If you just want to know that whether if they came to your form page from your landing page or not, you may add fix HTTP URL parameter prior to HTTP redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you save your rel in a variable, you can add it on your link to detailed page, for example in case of =fbads just once variable is set up, add it: `<a href="http://myDetailedPage.com/detailed/?=<?php $rel;?>"</a>`